# How to have a synchronized clock across 3 different components?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, synchronization

I am desiging a TOF measurement application. I am using following components from TI.
TDC7200, TDC1000, CC2538.
I want to have a synchronized clock across these three. MCU requires 32MHz, TDC sensors require 8Mhz-16Mhz, What are my options?

I came across clock generator CDCE913. But how do I electrically connect it to the MCU instead of the crystal oscilator? Is there any other better option to provide 32Mhz to MCU and synchronized 16Mhz to TDC components?

From the TI datasheet here is a block diagram of what I want to do,

[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: The cc2538 datasheet tells you precisely where you can feed a 32MHz input -pin 34.  Use a flip/flop to divide the 32MHz to 16MHz. You’ve not told us how synchronised you need the clocks. Picoseconds? Nanoseconds?

Comment: "MCU requires 32MHz" That sounds strange and unlikely. Every MCU made during the past 20 years or so comes with a tonne of built-in PLL/FLL that can be used internally to get whatever system clock you need.

Comment: @Lundin - datasheet says 32MHz. As soon as you make a sweeping statement, you know you’re going to be proven wrong! ‘Every mcu........’

Comment: @Kartman if I use a crystal, I should put it between pin 34-35. If I use clock generato cdce913, it has only one output. I should connect it to pin 34 and ground pin 35 via capacitor?

Comment: @Kartman "The datasheet of MSP430" no doubt. That's what, some 500 different parts at least? Some fairly new, some very old. Are you telling me no MSP430 ever made got an internal PLL?